# Hibernate class cast exception with Lists

Tags: java, hibernate, list, generics

So I have this code:

```
public List<FooRequirement> findByFoo(Foo foo) {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct fr.foo from FooBarRequirement fr where fr.Foo.id = :FooId")
            .setParameter("FooId", foo.getId()).list();
}
```

I call this code somewhere in my code with

```
List<FooRequirement> myList = dao.findByFoo(foo);
```

Then I got a ClassCastException and wondered what I was doing wrong. I debugged my code and I have seen that my list (myList) which is supposed to hold references of type FooRequirement objects is actually filled with references of type Foo.

Then I found my mistake:

```
return getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct fr from FooBarRequirement fr where fr.Foo.id = :FooId"
```

There was a **"select distinct fr.foo"** but it should have been a **"select distinct fr..."** because I want a List of FooRequirements not Foos.

My question is, how did that reference made itself into the List in the first place? I mean how is it possible for a List to hold a foo ?

Some information about the classes:

All of the classes are entities, the db has tables for them.

Foo class has a field id and a description.

FooRequirement class is an ABSTRACT class and has a reference to Foo (ManyToOne), and id. FooRequirement DOES NOT extend Foo.

FooBarRequirement class extends a FooRequirement class, if it is relavent. It has a field Baz. (ManyToOne)

I hope the question is clear. Actually the situation was a bit more complicated but I tried making it as simple as possible.

Comment: Well I don't understand your question. `I mean how is it possible for a List to hold a foo ?` - exactly what do you mean? Why can't a `List` hold a `foo`?

Comment: It is a List of FooRequirements. And Foo does not extend FooRequirement.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `List<FooBarRequirement>`?  From looking at your code, that's what Hibernate should have made.  And that, also, can't be cast to `List<FooRequirement>`.

Comment: I am sure it is a List<FooRequirement>

Comment: @Pisek Is this some kind of a joke?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code.  Kostja's answer is correct.  I was going to post the same thing myself, but there's no point in my repeating what Kostja has already written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly selecting Foo objects in your query `select distinct fr.foo...`

So this is the type that ends up in your `List`.

EDIT: You have defined the List you want to have as `List<FooRequirement>`. However the result list you get from the `Session` is not typed and thus can hold any `Object`, in your instance - `Foo`.

Since you cannot get a `TypedQuery` from a Hibernate `Session`, you might consider using the [`EntityManager` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

Comment: Isn 't the list only allowed to hold FooRequirement objects?

Comment: No, the result list you are trying to return has this restriction, but not the result list from the session.